# how do i get ALL images form a remote server using php/cURL

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

There are many examples on how to get a single image, but what is the PHP way  of getting ALL images

Comment: Do you know where the images are located on the server? In HTTP, you can't get nice directory indexes like in FTP (in most cases). You would either have to parse the HTML pages to look for images or already know where the images are located (unless the web server gives directory indexes - example: http://www.oleyvalleysd.org/BUILDINGS/).

Comment: Keep in mind you are asking to circumvent a lot of security blocks by doing requests such as this, in the case the remote server doesn't want this. Be careful about terms of use/service and laws in the area about mass-downloading images from a server. Just a thought!

Answer (score 2):

Please read: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Can_I_do_recursive_fetches_with

You can probably call `wget` through php and do something similar like this.

```
wget -A png,jpeg,jpg -r http://www.yoursite.com &
```

This will spawn an asynchronous operation and download all file endings listed with the -A option.

Comment: This will work, assuming the server allows linux calls, and that they are running on linux. Using wget assumes a LOT of things about the PHP configuration. But, if it is set up correctly, this is how I would do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found a webbot example in a book once.

Sample code :

http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/scripts/reader.php?show=image_capture_bot.php

You can download the LIB_download_images.php required by visiting the link below :
http://www.schrenk.com/nostarch/webbots/DSP_download.php

Good luck

Comment: Another way would be with the Developer Toolbar in Firefox where you can get a list of all the images found in the current webpage. Please note that not only the "Developer Toolbar for Firefox" can do that.