# Using phpcURL (libcurl) how can i download ONLY the images from a URL

Tags: php, libcurl

I want to use this to measure how long it takes to download images, then i can do the same measurement with other content types.

i found a relevant example: and sharing it.

```
# Parse the image tags 
$img_tag_array = parse_array($web_page['FILE'], ""); 
    if(count($img_tag_array)==0)
{echo "No images found at $target\n"; exit; }
```

The reson for DIY is to automate, this is part of a bigger framework.

Comment: Every URL references exactly one resource. There are no multiple images on "a URL".

Comment: @mario Well, he probably means "load a HTML page, scrape all image links, and download those"... But that's not really trivial. @kamal what do you need this for?

Comment: You asked this question a while ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630182/how-do-i-get-all-images-form-a-remote-server-using-php-curl

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it simple, Download Google Chrome and use the Web Developer tools to see detailed statistics on the time it takes to download the Image? It seems you are over complicating this, unless I am misunderstanding what exactly it is you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Found the function that does what i wanted, so i am sharing:

```
function download_images_for_page($target)
{
    echo "target = $target\n";

    # Download the web page
    $web_page = http_get($target, $referer="");

    # Update the target in case there was a redirection
    $target = $web_page['STATUS']['url'];

    # Strip file name off target for use as page base
    $page_base=get_base_page_address($target);

    # Identify the directory where iamges are to be saved
    $save_image_directory = "saved_images_".str_replace("http://", "", $page_base);

    # Parse the image tags
    $img_tag_array = parse_array($web_page['FILE'], "");

    if(count($img_tag_array)==0)
    {
        echo "No images found at $target\n";
        exit;
    }

    # Echo the image source attribute from each image tag
    for($xx=0; $xx
```